# NLog.Extensions.Logging structured logs

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

I am trying to use NLog provider for logging in my .net core application. I am using the sample code on GitHub website. Formatted logging works just fine but structured logging doesn't seem to work. I am using the following code to initialise logger

```
var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
loggerFactory.AddNLog();
NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");
```

Logger is injected into the application using Microsoft DI, and the logging statement looks like, where action is instance of some complex type

```
_logger.LogInformation("Test {@action}", action);
```

If I don't use the Microsoft logging abstraction and instantiate the logger using NLog Log manager, structured logging works fine

```
NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");
_logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

And if I use SeriLog with Microsoft logging abstraction it also works fine. Both the formatted log and structured logs work using the following code to initialise logger

```
loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();
```

It got me thinking, only possible explanation is NLog.Extensions.Logging (provided jointly by Microsoft and NLog) doesn't yet support structured logging, even though Nlog does. I couldn't find any information to say it doesn't do it.

Can someone please confirm whether or not it's supported and hopefully point to a working example?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/pull/202

Comment: Right now NLog just uses the Microsoft Extension Logging engine for parsing and formatting log-messages. It doesn't support destructure and stringify. I guess NLog could startup its own parser when detecting such a case.

Comment: Have now created https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/pull/213 that can enable the NLog MessageTemplate Parse automatically when making use of destructure @ . It will generate a some overhead as the Microsoft Extension Logging already have spent time on parsing, and now NLog will do it again.

Comment: NLog.Extensions.Logging ver. 1.1.0 has been released. It adds support for message-template-capturetype handling int Microsoft Extension Logging: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Extension Logging supports structured logging, but not messagetemplate specification of `@` and `$`

NLog uses the Microsoft Extension Logging formatter for the `${message}`, because Microsoft Extension Logging has already spent time on parsing and formatting the input-template.

NLog is able to harvest the logging parameters along with specification of `@` and `$`. This is used by `JsonLayout` that will automatically use them for correct json-serialization of the structured-logging-properties (When MaxRecursionLimit is 1 or higher)

Comment: Have now created https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/pull/213 that can enable the NLog MessageTemplate Parse automatically when making use of destructure @ .

Comment: Has this been pulled into NLog.Web.AspNetCore, too? Or is otherwise available there?

Comment: @Fildor Yes. Since NLog.Web.AspNetCore depends on NLog.Extensions.Logging